# Save a batch of frames as video using opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I need to buffer some frames from a VideoCapture and then save the latest *n* frames

This works:

```
from cv2 import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

buffered_frames = []

frame = 0

frames_to_record = 180

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()

    if not success:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Stream", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(fps) == ord('q'):
        break

    frame += 1
    buffered_frames.append(img)

    
    if frame % 500 == 0:
        result = cv2.VideoWriter("./buffer.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, (width, height))

        for f in buffered_frames[ frame-frames_to_record: ]:
            result.write(f)

        result.release()
        buffered_frames = []
        frame = 0

cap.release()
```

However, I'm looking for some way to optimize this, saving the frames as a batch, so, instead of:

```
for f in buffered_frames[ frame-frames_to_record: ]:
    result.write(f)
```

I'm looking for a way to save all the list at once, something like:

```
result.write(buffered_frames[ frame-frames_to_record: ])
```

But, the example above doesn't work, is there a way to save a batch of frames at once using OpenCV? (So it have some low-level optimization under the hood)

Comment: no, there is no such API.

Comment: Not that I know of. What makes you think there might be some optimisation under the hood? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarkSetchell usually, write a chunk of data to the storage is faster than write the same amount of data at small portions at time, so, maybe there is some optimization at storage level, but, apparently there's no such kind of optimization at API level, as Christoph Rackwitz said. Thank you, anyways

Comment: Are you maybe worried that your program gets slower and unresponsive when you output the 100 frames *en masse*? If so, there are other options - you could save the frames as you go, or use multi-threading, for example.